# Customizing what Ember Data sends to the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Two of the models in my application are `projects` and `users`. Projects can have many users assigned to them and vice versa. I'm using Ember Data, so my model looks like this:

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  created: DS.attr('date'),
  users: DS.hasMany('App.User')
});
```

When creating a project on the server, the API expects to receive the project's name AND an array of IDs corresponding to the project's users. So, basically, something like this:

```
POST /projects
{
  project: {
    name: 'My Project',
    users: [1, 10, 14]
  }
}
```

However, Ember Data isn't including the array of user IDs when sending a POST or PUT request. By default, it only includes the name attribute. How can I modify Ember Data to include what I need? Is it even worth doing, or should I go the Discourse route and abandon Ember Data for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version and the RESTAdapter/RESTSerializer, you can override the addHasMany method of the serializer.

So, here is an example of how to do this:

```
App.CustomSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  addHasMany: function(hash, record, key, relationship) {
    var ids = record.get(relationship.key).map(function(item) {
      return item.get('id');
    });

    hash[relationship.key] = ids;
  },
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    serializer: App.CustomSerializer.create()
  })
});
```

Note that the addHasMany implementation is taken from https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/fixture_serializer.js#L41

Comment: Nice, thank you. It's worth nothing that simply calling `get` didn't work for me (line 3 of your code). I had to actually do `record.get(relationship.key)`.

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll good catch thanks. As I said, I copy/paste the one in the FixtureAdapter, so internally ember.js use the Ember.get method. I fix   it.